# What Java library can retrieve data from a remote URL, while handing various content encodings?

Tags: java, http

I've rolled my own code to retrieve data from remote URLs using a HttpURLConnection.  First I had to write custom code to handle gzipped content encoding, now I am encountering web servers that are serving up RSS feeds with a chunked Transfer-Encoding.  I'm finding myself reimplementing a bunch of stuff that I'm sure has already been done.

I'm sure there is some library that will automatically handle the various ways that data can be returned from a web server and just give me an InputStream, can anyone recommend one (must be LGPL or similar license)?

Ideally I'm looking for a library that is currently maintained and which has a modern well-designed API.

In some cases I won't know the Content-type that will be returned in advance, and so may need to handle what is returned differently depending on this.

Comment: My first idea would be to look at [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) – I don't know for sure it supports all your requirements, but it might considering how long it's been around for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know Apache Commons HttpComponents supports Content-Encoding as of 4.1+ (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941704/47773)), using [`ContentEncodingHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/ContentEncodingHttpClient.html).  [`DecompressingHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DecompressingHttpClient.html) should also work for 4.2+ (they have slightly different behavior in conjunction with caching).

Like millimoose said, it may not have everything.  But I think it will be a better starting place.

Comment: But what if you don't know whether the content will be encoded or compressed before you attempt to retrieve it?

Comment: @sanity, I believe that's fine.  `DecompressingHttpClient` will ask for compressed content using Accept-Encoding, but will check the Content-Encoding to determine if the response actually was compressed.