# A bit confused about HttpClient[Java] handling gzip responses

Tags: java, gzip, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

My application makes a http request to some api service, that service returns a gzipped response. How can I make sure that the response is indeed in gzip format? I'm confused at why after making the request I didn't have to decompress it.

Below is my code:

```
public static String streamToString(InputStream stream) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error while streaming to string: {}", e);
    } finally {
        try { stream.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public static String getResultFromHttpRequest(String url) throws IOException { // add retries, catch all exceptions
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    InputStream stream;

    try {
        httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        logger.info(httpResponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding());
        logger.info(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            stream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            return streamToString(stream);
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        logger.error("Error while trying to access: " + url, e);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Maybe it is decompressing it automatically, but I would like to see some indication of that at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Apache Commons HttpClient support GZIP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777076/does-apache-commons-httpclient-support-gzip)

Comment: @jtahlborn kinda but not exactly.

Comment: If the environment allows you to do so, a very quick check could have been capturing the traffic (Wireshark, Tcpdump...) between the app and the server. As HTTP is a text based protocol, if the response has the right header and the body is composed mostly of non-readable characters, it looks like the response is compressed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi I am late but this answer might by used who is facing same issue.
By default content is decompressed in the response. So, you have to disable the default compression using following code:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .disableContentCompression()
    .build();

HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlSring);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request, context);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Header contentEncodingHeader = entity.getContentEncoding();

if (contentEncodingHeader != null) {
    HeaderElement[] encodings =contentEncodingHeader.getElements();
    for (int i = 0; i < encodings.length; i++) {
        if (encodings[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            entity = new GzipDecompressingEntity(entity);
            break;
        }
    }
}

String output = EntityUtils.toString(entity, Charset.forName("UTF-8").name());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use [DecompressingHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DecompressingHttpClient.html) (or the new [HttpClientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) - which adds that header by default, don't call disableContentCompression - I don't think `DefaultHttpClient` supports compression by default). The client needs to send an [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#accept-encoding) header, Content-Encoding comes from the server response.

Comment: @yaojiang It changes so often! I added the HttpClientBuilder, which seems to be the more modern method.

Comment: @yaojiang: HttpClientBuilder is not deprecated

Answer (score 2):

```
httpResponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding()
```

You can find out whether or not an entity requires decompression by examining its `Content-Encoding` header. This header will be rewritten (or removed) in case of automatic content decompression.

Comment: when i get the response, i did a sysout for the contentencoding, but it is coming out as empty string, does that mean it was automatic?

Comment: @yaojiang: absence of explicit 'Content-Encoding' header implies identity encoding, that is, no encoding

Comment: when i enter the api url on firefox, i do see that the response headers contain "content-encoding = gzip", "content-length = 278", "content-type = application/json, charset=utf-8", "vary = Accept-Encoding"

Comment: @yaojiang: So what? You can disable automatic content decompression or execute with wire logging on to see raw HTTP message composition

Comment: @oleg so what, what? What he means is that the response contains a content-encoding set to gzip but the http response object does not display it. I'm running into that issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.1, Apache HttpClients handles request and response compression. You can check the example in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777076/does-apache-commons-httpclient-support-gzip/46910651#46910651).

Still in case you want to check whether the response was compressed or not. You can print the class of the entity.

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
System.out.println(httpEntity.getClass().getName());
```

In case of `gzip` the output will be `org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity` & for `deflate` its `org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity`