# How to Send GZIP (Accept­Encoding : ​ gzip ) parameter in Request header Of Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, gzip

I'm trying to send

```
headers.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

in my Spring boot application.

I'm getting this Exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
```

But I need to send gzip as request header.

My Spring boot Version is '1.3.5.RELEASE'

Please help me out.

My Request Example:

```
url = apiUrl + apiMethod + "?api_key=" + apiKey;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("api_key", apiKey);
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.set("Accept-Encoding", "x-gzip");
HttpEntity < String > entity = new HttpEntity < String > ("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity < GenericResponseDto > response = null;
try {
    response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
        GenericResponseDto.class);
    log.info("Response :" + response.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new CustomException(e, aPIAuditTrail);
}
```

Comment: It might not be related to header. Could you (a) share the controller and request example and (b) try without header?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful

Comment: Yeah I have tried with that but didn't get the solution.

Comment: But I got solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415144/cannot-parse-gzip-encoded-response-with-resttemplate-from-spring-web

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve the same issue without using additional libraries.
What helped me was to

1. change the responseType from the entity type (GenericResponseDto) to byte[].class
2. unzipping response myself
3. mapping the entity myself by ObjectMapper mapper.

It is not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<byte[]>(new HttpHeaders()), byte[].class);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody()))) {
        gzipInputStream.transferTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
    }
    byte[] content = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    GenericResponseDto question = mapper.readValue(content, GenericResponseDto .class);  
    log.info("Response :" + question.toString());
```