# Spring Boot RestTemplate WebClient - Response Body JSON Empty

Tags: spring-boot, httpresponse, resttemplate, spring-webclient

I am using Rest Template and have used Web Client as well. I get the key in response but the body is empty always. Using Postman I can see the Response which is a JSON.

My code snippet is below -

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBasicAuth("john", "doe");

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "https://www.getMeData.com",
            HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

    System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

**Response** is as below -

> {"result":[]}

Has anyone faced the same issue?

In Postman the Response Headers I can see is -

**KEY**              **VALUE**

Content-Encoding     *gzip*

Content-Type         *application/json;charset=UTF-8*

Transfer-Encoding    *chunked*

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the Restemplate exchange method parameter from **String url** to ***new URI("url")*** and it worked.

```
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(new URI("https://www.getMeData.com"),
        HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me when passing URL with params like "https://www.google.com?find=abc".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add headers as below:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth("john", "doe");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

 HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

 For gZip - use
```

Gzip is disabled by default, check whether it's enabled on your application. If not enable Gzip with properties

```
server.compression.enabled=true  
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json  
server.compression.min-response-size=1024
```

And add below encoding to test

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

You can also try with creating a new Http message convertor and add the same to RestTemplate instance before invoking remote api call..

Comment: Already tried it. No Luck!!!
I guess it can be the encoding to gzip by Gzip or Transfer encoding set to chunked!!!

Comment: Tried with content encoding as gzip??

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415144/how-to-parse-gzip-encoded-response-with-resttemplate-in-spring-web

Answer (score 0):

Spring implementation simply does not support it.

From the [HTTP 1.1 2014 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-24):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Having that stated this is how you should refactor your code to make it work:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        "https://www.getMeData.com",
        HttpMethod.POST, // <- this is it
        request, String.class);
```

If you have no control over controller method layout - switch to `python` + `requests` library to have this done.