# Spring Integration GZIP HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, gzip, spring-ws

I need to compress HTTP requests over outbound-gateway. Is there a `GZIPInterceptor` for Spring Integration or other thing for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box, but it's easy enough to add a pair of transformers to zip the payload before sending to the gateway...

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "gzipIt", outputChannel = "gzipped")
public byte[] gzip(byte[] in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzOut = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, gzOut);
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

and another to unzip...

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "gUnzipIt", outputChannel = "gUnzipped")
public byte[] gUnzip(byte[] in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPInputStream gzIn = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(in));
    FileCopyUtils.copy(gzIn, out);
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

You can also do it in a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

Also see the link in Artem's comment below.

Comment: The Apache HTTP Client supports that by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777076/does-apache-commons-httpclient-support-gzip and you can configure Spring Integration HTTP to use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`